# How to differentiate between codepush and storepush

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am currently building an App using react-native where we are integrating it with Codepush service.
I know that we can explicitly call Codepush server from build script using  command like -

```
appcenter codepush release-react
```

However, as per my requirement, my build pipeline should not release a codepush and instead force for a full app upgrade if the code changes are not in .js files. (let's say changes are in image or logo then I should not go ahead with codepush)

My question is, is there any standard way to check that from appcenter build scripts?

Comment: Prior to RN 0.60 I had my script to check if anything was modified in `android/` or `ios/` folder and then create a native binary. Otherwise, just do a JS bundle. But with new version >= 0.60 there is no change in android or ios folders. I am stuck with the same issue.